# Expression tree, listFoo.Where(lambda) throws invalid argument error

Tags: c#, lambda

Why the below code throws '... has some invalid arguments at'

```
    var qry = listFoo.Where(lambda);
```

How should i write my listFoo inorder to call the Where on it by passing the predicate delegate. My entire code follow below,

```
    List<Foo> listFoo = new List<Foo>();

    ParameterExpression foo = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "foo");
    MemberExpression bar = Expression.PropertyOrField(foo, "Bar");
    ConstantExpression abc = Expression.Constant("abc", typeof(string)); 
    BinaryExpression test = Expression.Equal(bar, abc);

    Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, bool>>(test, foo);

    var qry = listFoo.Where(lambda);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your list is not IQueryable. Why don't you just do this?

```
var qry = listFoo.Where(foo => foo.Bar == "abc");
```

If you can't do that, do this:

```
var qry = listFoo.Where(lambda.Compile()); //warning, slow performance
```

Comment: (or `.AsQueryable().Where(lambda)`)

Comment: Internally, this does the same thing. It just covers it up.

Comment: @usr: Actually, Kirk's suggestion is different in that it allows downstream analysis of the expression from the queryable.

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ extension methods on IEnumerable take delegate instances (either `Action<>` or `Func<>` objects). Lambdas are just delegate literals, so in this case it won't take an `Expression<Func<>>` because you're giving it a PLAN, not a delegate. That's all an Expression is, is a plan for how to handle some data. IQueryable takes Expressions (and the compiler treats the delegate literals as `Expression`s) so that it can take the plans and consolidate (if they can be reduced).

For IEnumerable, you have to call `Compile()` on the `Expression<Func<>>` before you pass it to the `Where` method. However, you CAN do this:

```
var qry = listFoo.AsQueryable().Where(lambda);
```

However, this will give you an `IQueryable<Foo>` result, so you'd still need to do `AsEnumerable`, `ToList`, `ToArray`, etc.

Comment: Not understanding what you mean by "IQueryable takes Expressions (and casts the delegate literals as Expressions)"

Comment: `IQueryable<T>` LINQ extension methods take `Expression<Func<>>` or `Expression<Action<>>` as parameters, however you can still pass a delegate literal (a lambda, ie `ti => ti > 5`) and it will treat it as an expression (the compiler will). In fact, if you were to try to declare an implicitly typed lambda (`var lam = (ti) => ti + 5;`), you'll see that the compiler complains because it doesn't know what to treat it as (`Expression` or `Func<>/Action<>`).